# C# - Colorbox - not displaying images correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox modal plugin found at

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

I went through the demos and everything seemed very simple and easy to use. This is the example I went by:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css">
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class='gallery' href='image1.jpg'>Photo_1</a>
        <a class='gallery' href='image2.jpg'>Photo_2</a>
        <a class='gallery' href='image3.jpg'>Photo_3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

which work perfectly in a simple html file environment. However, when I try to extend this to an ASP.NET master page by putting the stuff from the  tags in my master file, my other pages don't recognize it. In fact, if I put it in the  tags on the individual pages, it won't recognize anything either. I even tried making a reference to the original URL instead of local .js files, but no luck. This is how I am calling it in my master file:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

and this is how I am using it in my .aspx pages:

```
<p>        
    <a class="gallery" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/African_Bush_Elephant.jpg">elephant</a>
    <a class="gallery" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/African_Bush_Elephant.jpg">elephant</a>
    <a class="gallery" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/African_Bush_Elephant.jpg">elephant</a>
</p>
```

I feel like I followed the tutorial perfectly. Can anyone give me a lead as to what I may be doing wrong? This is incredibly frustrating (and btw, not the first shadowbox I've ever done in my life, but this is the first time I've had so much trouble with them and I blame VS2012).

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being much simpler than I thought. First off, you want to make sure this portion:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1' });
    });
</script>
```

is in the .aspx (or .html) file you want it to run in, not your master page. Second off, if you are using ASP.NET default site settings, you will be given a lot of bloat, including this little gem to run scripts:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
            <%--Framework scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Unless you are using some script in the above ScriptManager, just comment this out. Then call your normal scripts the way you usually do in the  tags.

My final master page looked like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
<%--            <Scripts>--%>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
                <%--Framework scripts--%>
<%--                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />--%>
                <%--Site scripts--%>
<%--            </Scripts>--%>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">
                        <a runat="server" href="~/">your logo here</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                            <AnonymousTemplate>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a id="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </AnonymousTemplate>
                            <LoggedInTemplate>
                                <p>
                                    Hello, <a runat="server" class="username" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">
                                        <asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" />
                                    </a>!
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                                </p>
                            </LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>
                        &copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my default.aspx looked like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
                    $(".group1").colorbox({ rel: 'group1' });
                    $(".group2").colorbox({ rel: 'group2', transition: "fade" });
                    $(".group3").colorbox({ rel: 'group3', transition: "none", width: "75%", height: "75%" });
                    $(".group4").colorbox({ rel: 'group4', slideshow: true });
                    $(".ajax").colorbox();
                    $(".youtube").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 640, innerHeight: 390 });
                    $(".vimeo").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 500, innerHeight: 409 });
                    $(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%" });
                    $(".inline").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" });
                    $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                        onOpen: function () { alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                        onLoad: function () { alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                        onComplete: function () { alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                        onCleanup: function () { alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                        onClosed: function () { alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
                    });

                    $('.non-retina').colorbox({ rel: 'group5', transition: 'none' })
                    $('.retina').colorbox({ rel: 'group5', transition: 'none', retinaImage: true, retinaUrl: true });

                    //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
                    $("#click").click(function () {
                        $('#click').css({ "background-color": "#f00", "color": "#fff", "cursor": "inherit" }).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                        return false;
                    });
                });
        </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
                <h2>Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET application.</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                To learn more about ASP.NET, visit <a href="http://asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">http://asp.net</a>. 
                The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from 
                ASP.NET. If you have any questions about ASP.NET visit 
                <a href="http://forums.asp.net/18.aspx" title="ASP.NET Forum">our forums</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
    <ol class="round">
        <li class="one">
            <h5>Getting Started</h5>
            ASP.NET Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model.
            A design surface and hundreds of controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful UI-driven sites with data access.
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245146">Learn more…</a>
        </li>
        <li class="two">
            <h5>Add NuGet packages and jump-start your coding</h5>
            NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools.
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245147">Learn more…</a>
        </li>
        <li class="three">
            <h5>Find Web Hosting</h5>
            You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245143">Learn more…</a>
        </li>
    </ol>

    These are images: <br />
    <a class="group1" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">sign.</a> <br />
    <a class="group1" href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02368/potd-cowboy-cat_2368962k.jpg">cat.</a><br />
    <a class="group1" href="http://www.nonags.com/funimg/dogiedoll.jpg">dog.</a><br />

    <a class="group2" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">sign.</a> <br />
    <a class="group2" href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02368/potd-cowboy-cat_2368962k.jpg">cat.</a><br />
    <a class="group2" href="http://www.nonags.com/funimg/dogiedoll.jpg">dog.</a><br />

    <a class="group3" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">sign.</a> <br />
    <a class="group3" href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02368/potd-cowboy-cat_2368962k.jpg">cat.</a><br />
    <a class="group3" href="http://www.nonags.com/funimg/dogiedoll.jpg">dog.</a><br />

    <a class="group4" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">sign.</a> <br />
    <a class="group4" href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02368/potd-cowboy-cat_2368962k.jpg">cat.</a><br />
    <a class="group4" href="http://www.nonags.com/funimg/dogiedoll.jpg">dog.</a><br />


</asp:Content>
```